# Name for a type of subgraph that comes from identification of vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Is there a special name for the kind of subgraphs you get by taking some sequence of the following operation:  Pick two vertices and identify them so all edges going to either vertex get sent to the new vertex.

Comment: Note that if you contract only adjacent vertices of a graph $G$ you obtain a minor of $G$.

Comment: Here is link to [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_%28graph_theory%29) on minors mentioned in Azoo's comment.

Comment: I'm actually doing the opposite here and only contracting vertices which are not adjacent.  My graph is the Hasse graph of a ranked poset and my identifications take place between vertices of the same rank.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't get a subgraph when you do that, but what you might call a *quotient* graph instead (the natural map goes the other way). The operation is called [vertex contraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction).

Comment: I like the name for this as it goes along with identification similar to the quotient topology.  Thank you!  (I was aware the output would not necessarily be a subgraph cause it's easy to see the maximal and average degree can increase, but I poorly phrased my question and used subgraph there instead of output.)